# Nexus: How to download a gzipped or other compressed file in a script tag?

Tags: javascript, html, http, networking, nexus

I can upload an umd.min.js or umd.min.js.gz or umd.min.br file to nexus or all of them.

Now I want to use them in a  tag, while compressing the data during transfer, so save data, and speeding up the download.

I tried the following:

```js
    <script src="https://{linktoNexusRepo}/someFile.umd.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://{linktoNexusRepo}/someFile.umd.min.js.gz"></script>
    <script src="https://{linktoNexusRepo}/someFile.umd.min.js.br"></script>
    <script src="https://{linktoNexusRepo}/someFile.umd.min.js.gz" type="application/x-brotli"></script>
    <script src="https://{linktoNexusRepo}/someFile.umd.min.js.gz" type="application/javascript"></script>
```

The Problems I encountered:

- When loading the .gz or .br files: The resource from “https://repo.vidis.schule/repository/vidis-cdn-snapshots/1.10.0-snapshot/vidisLogin.umd.js.br” was blocked due to MIME type (“application/x-brotli”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff) => The Mime-Types are not compatible, or nexus has to stop setting the no-sniff X-Content-Type-Options Header
- When loading the .gz or .br files: The Request is accepted with 200 but no data is being transferred. Directly using the nexus download link works however.
- When loading the .js file, the data is not compressed. In particular the Content-Encoding is not being set: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Encoding

Comment: If the server is not setting the appropriate "Content-Type" and "Content-Encoding" headers. then this is a server configuration issue.

Comment: Correct. To my knowledge, the Nexus is currently in that role in our case. So how do I configure Nexus to provide the correct headers?  Or would you say, that there has to be some kind of proxy in between because Nexus can't do that?